# What is the alternative for WP_List_Table CLass in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress plugin developers use `WP_List_Table` class for build HTML tables in admin panel.

But, WordPress official documentation has following note in [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table).

> This class's access is marked as private. That means it is not
>   intended for use by plugin and theme developers as it is subject to
>   change without warning in any future WordPress release. If you would
>   still like to make use of the class, you should make a copy to use and
>   distribute with your own project, or else use it at your own risk.

Then, what is the alternative to build HTML tables in WordPress admin panel?

Comment: They're suggesting you just copy paste and rename the class, then use it. So just do that!

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative to this.

But what you can do is copy and rename the `WP_List_Table` class. So it won't be affected if WordPress changes the class or the class becomes deprecated.

Comment: What did you mean by rename the class? I need to just rename the class name? Or more works to done?

Answer (score -1):

You can make your own admin pages based in the html of pages like "pages" or "post", create a view for add, another for edit and for list obviously, you have to create your custom page by add_menu in the functions.php and create your own file. Once you have that file you can do whatever you want. You can also work with your own custom tables into wordpress database.

Of course all depend what you want to do, but my suggestion is to use `WP_List_Table` Class.